# waffle cones for serving lattes

Tags: coffee

I melted agar agar in almost boiling water and reduced the temperature to 115 F.

I then coated the inside of waffle cones with the liquid. My cones are soggy.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this.

Any suggestions for other ways to waterproof the inside of waffle cones and still keep them crispy?

I want to serve hot and iced lattes in these cones in my coffee shop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Mary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coating to make waffle cones withstand hot liquid?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27192/coating-to-make-waffle-cones-withstand-hot-liquid)

Comment: I think most liquid will render the waffle cone unusable very quickly, hot or cold whatever the coating you will use, or the coating will change the taste of the coffee itself (using chocolate for example).

Comment: @moscafj the answer to the proposed duplicate suggests agar agar, which seems to not have worked!

Comment: have you ever seen this done successfully ? Using the latte to make an ice cream/custard/yogurt might get the flavor profile you are looking for

Comment: @Erica I believe we identify questions as duplicates, whether or not the answers are correct, or worked.  This can also serve to bring renewed attention to a question or issue.  My reading of the duplicate question, however, leads me to believe an edible solution is unlikely.

Comment: I agree with @moscafj. This question is a duplicate regardless of answers to the other. If that question didn't get a satisfactory answer, it is unlikely that this one will. Either way, this question is a dupe.

Comment: I think it depends on whether OP wants to focus on the agar agar as a solution (how to use it as a coating without making the cones soggy), or look for any ideas (in which case it's a duplicate). For example, "agar agar will never work for this" that's an answer to this question, not to the duplicate. In contrast, "you can waterproof a waffle cone with [substance]" would be an answer to either this or the duplicate, and then the question becomes a duplicate.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because agar agar was in the leading answer to the other question.  The asker here is trying that and it isn't working for her.