# What food can contain a hot drink?

Tags: ingredient-selection, heat, containers

Tempered chocolate, thickened caramel, even ice can all be used to produce a container (aka cup, mug, glass) for a liquid which, after drinking, can then also be consumed.

Is there an edible material which can be used to create a container for a hot drink? eg: Hot chocolate or coffee?

The other requirement is that this needs to be fairly straightforward to make at home; I'm aware of an espresso cup available in Italy, but this is using industrial techniques by professionals.

I have wondered about using brandy snap, but have only just learned how to make them, so have not had time to experiment.

Comment: I wouldn't fancy picking up a brandy snap full of hot drink -- it would probably soften with the heat

Comment: Any brandy snap I've ever met was full of holes!

Comment: Well, I wondered about it - not saying it's a good idea.

Comment: Any container can be consumed if you're brave enough.

Answer (score 3):

Bread bowls are frequently used to serve thick soups, so they could probably hold coffee or hot chocolate.  [Here is a patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6068866) application for an edible cup.  It might give you some ideas.  See also, [this project](http://www.dianeleclairbisson.com/jelly-bowls/), where an industrial designer is attempting to replace disposable containers with edible ones.  Probably critical is how hot your liquid will be, and how long you want it to be contained.

Answer (score 3):

Dense, hard bread was used as plates, historically - trenchers - even for foods that can be generously sauced.  Some of the liquid might soak in, but the structure should remain sound.

I would imagine a dense cracker, like hardtack, could be shaped into a cup and baked hard, and then used without leaking.  A fluffy/airy cracker would sog up pretty quickly, and in a richer dough fats might lift out with heat (and leave openings for liquid), but a simple flour-and-water dough could probably be made sturdy enough to hold liquid without dissolving for some time.  Maybe like [salt dough ornaments](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/11126/dough-ornament-recipe/), only without enough salt to be inedible?  Perhaps sugar instead?  or [edible play-dough](http://www.cricketsdailyfix.com/food/edible-platescupsutensils/) recipes, may become sturdy after baking?  Should work for "sturdy", anyway.

It would be tricky to balance sturdiness with palatability, though, as a generously sturdy cup would tend to be both tough and tasteless (and dry), a thinner one my be less sturdy, and one that can soften or gain flavorings from the liquid would have to be carefully timed not to soak too quickly.

You might manage something with an unleavened sweet cracker, or a *very* hard/crunchy cookie, rolled out on the thinner side so it can be comfortably bitten into once the liquid is drunk.  Perhaps spices can give it flavor, as too much sugar will disrupt the cracker's consistency as it dissolves.  It may be helpful to dry before baking, as is done with clay, to prevent cracking or the formation of air pockets... since docking will be counterproductive.  Or perhaps baked twice, to draw off extra moisture.

Comment: Perhaps, combining some of your ideas, a flatbread dough baked pressed into a bowl, lining it, then toasted

Comment: Hardtack would definitely work in the sense that it's edible and can easily retain liquids. I recently came back from a yachting trip where we used it as an ingredient for soup. We smashed the things to little pieces and boiled them in the soup for an hour or so, and even after that, they were quite hard and crunchy. The things are very dense and extremely hard when dry.

Answer (score 2):

Someone [already asked](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/90587/waffle-cones-for-serving-lattes) and [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27192/coating-to-make-waffle-cones-withstand-hot-liquid) a while back, and most of the answer revolve around using a "gel" coating like agar-agar on edible stuff like waffles.

The thing is that liquid and hot liquid will dissolve a lot of food stuff, either fat,  sugar, salt, or baked things like waffles, cookies, snaps of all kind.